# Build link (url) for calendar event

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to build a url link from event, so I can use this url in my web app as a clickable link. After click on event I want to see opened event, where I can edit this event
I found this, but its not working correctly:

```
var calendarId = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(MYCAL).getId();

var splitEventId = event.getId().split('@');
var eventURL = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit/" + Utilities.base64Encode(splitEventId[0] + " " + calendarId);
```

Output (eventURL) is URL:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit/MGtxajM4bjZnaDljdGZrczloNzdlZmFsM3IgbWFydGluLmJpZWxhazFAZ21haWwuY29t
```

But original URL to event is :

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit/MGtxajM4bjZnaDljdGZrczloNzdlZmFsM3IgbWFydGluLmJpZWxhazFAbQ
```

It is almost matching, but end of URL is different. I tried also without space between `splitEventId` and `calendarId`, but output was worst.
Does somebody know, why this is happening?
How can I build,get event URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This link will help you: Google Calender v3

And the way to build this url is:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId
```

where `calendarId` & `eventId` are parametres.

Hope this is helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get)

> **HTTP request**
>
> ```
> GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId
> ```

Important parameters needed:

> **calendarId** - Calendar identifier. To retrieve calendar IDs call the [calendarList.list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) method. If you want to access the primary
>   calendar of the currently logged in user, use the "**primary**"
>   keyword.
>
> **eventId** - Event identifier.

You can also use the [Try it now](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get#try-it) to check if you have provided a valid/correct data for the required parameters.